# How to make split buttons

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'm trying to make a similar UI. Tell me how you can implement split custom buttons as shown on the screen. I'm more interested in how to make a custom form for buttons. As you can see, it blends into the background of the container.

I understand that ordinary containers can not do here. We need something more custom.

[image]

I am considering using ordinary containers, but here it should be noted that something is more custom. It is possible to look towards CustomPainter??

Comment: You could try and look into flex this way you can make a `row( Expanded ( flex: 3) Expanded (felx: 4) )` and you will have 1 "container" with multiple buttons in a row.

Comment: I need to achieve the effect so that the buttons are separated. how to achieve this using flex ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can use flex in a row to have two seperate buttons next to each other. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
         Row(
            children: <Widget> [
              Expanded(
                // with the flex you give the width
                flex: 9,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Configuration'),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      //styling button
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              Expanded(
                // with the flex you give the width
                  flex: 9,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Rack 3'),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      // styling button
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ]
        ),
```